# prepopulate dropdown value with selected index from JSON

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I am trying to achieve a small functionality. I have rows with text boxes and drop-downs for all the values will come as a array from server side. I can able to bind all the data to the client side,except the selected value for the drop down (it always point to the first one in the drop-down list).kindly show me how can I make the selected value as active, when data is populated from the server side.

```
 <select class="ddText" id="selType" data-bind="options:typeDropDown, optionsText: 'Value', optionsValue: 'Value',value : Type,attr: { name: 'age',id : 'str_'+$index()}, uniqueName:true" "></select>
```

I have tried adding attribute to the value bind in the above code. like this (value : Type.Value - works when populate from JSON , while creating new rows with that getting error **"Can't find the property value for the Type"**)

[Dropdowns and JSON Objects and Binding the selected value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17711472/dropdowns-and-json-objects-and-binding-the-selected-value)

Since I have a functionality of creating dynamic rows, I am getting error while creating new rows .

Do I need to rebuild my array?

**Update**

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    //Available types - which will come from serverside
    self.typeDropDown = ko.observableArray(InitialData);

    self.typeValue = ko.observable();

//Explicitly Adding new Row
    self.Inputs = ko.observableArray([new Item(self.typeDropDown[0], '', '', '')]);

    self.removeRow = function (Item) {
        self.Inputs.remove(Item);
    },
    self.addNewRow = function () {
        //push will add a new element to the container without modifying much in DOM
        self.Inputs.push(new Item(self.typeDropDown[0], '', '', ''));
    }
```

Comment: Please post your viewmodel.

Comment: @Tuan:Updated my Question

Comment: I also need to see how you've defined Item and InitialData.

Comment: It is an srray 0: Object

ID: "24"
Key: "Str"
Value: "SAAN1"

1: Object

ID: "25"
Key: "Str"
Value: "NASA1"

2: Object

ID: "26"
Key: "Str"
Value: "Object1" captured from the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value is bound to Type, but you don't have a Type property defined in your ViewModel function.

It should work if you add something like:

```
self.Type = ko.observable("NASA1");
```

to your viewmodel.

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zxJV6/) for an example.

Comment: Thanks, i will try and let you know.